# Grok Pattern escaping a - (hyphen)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to write a grok pattern for something like 123-543, which is two numbers separated by a hyphen.
I've written a grok %{NUMBER:num1}-%{NUMBER:num2} by escaping the hyphen but it's not working.
Alsi attached a screenshot by testing it on a online grok debugger. Can someone help me? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Ory.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the grok pattern here:

```
%{INT:num1}\-%{INT:num2}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! what is the difference between NUMBER and INT, if I may ask?

Comment: You Welcome. :) Also, you can use POSINT. You can get the difference [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)

Comment: Thanks man. I was searching this exact ans. :)